# Better way to find if a number is present in between two numbers of a sorted list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a sorted list like this

```
s = [1 , 4 ,6 , 9  ,10 ]
```

I want to know if either a number is present in the list or if it is present in between two numbers. If it is present in between two numbers, I want to print them out.

Right now my code looks like this

```
for x in s:
   if b == x: \\ b is the number
       print b
   elif b > x and b < s[s.index(x) + 1] and s.index(x) < len(s):
       print b , s[s.index(x) + 1]
```

Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: What's your intended behaviour if `b = 11`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[bisect module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) does exactly that:

```
s = [1 , 4 ,6 , 9  ,10 ]
import bisect

x = 5
n = bisect.bisect_left(s, x)
if s[n:n+1] == [x]:
    print x, 'is in the list'
else:
    print x, 'comes between', s[n-1:n], 'and', s[n:n+1]
```

Comment: @manoj Just need to be careful where `bisect_left()` is `0` or `len(s)`... eg: `x = 11` gives `11 comes between [10] and []` so maybe: `elif n not in (0, len(s)): # comes between`... `else: # no match`

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect optimized, but you can avoid using index() method many times!

```
for i,j in enumerate(s,1):
 if b == j: \\ b is the number
   print b
 elif b > j and b < s[i+1] and s[i] < len(s):
   print b , s[i + 1]
```